# How to add a new column in my already created table using sql command

Tags: php, sql

How can I add a new column (like `email`) in my already created table `students` using sql command?

In my `students` table I already have two columns name `id` and `name`. It was created using this sql command

```
CREATE TABLE students(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY id);
```

Comment: you want a query to insert data on your table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I corrected your little language mistakes, hopefully it's really what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ALTER` statement to add new column in existing table.

```
ALTER TABLE students ADD email VARCHAR(100);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it was greate and sloved.